# For HTTP responses with Content-Types suggesting character data, which charset should be assumed by the client if none is specified?

Tags: http, default, content-type, character-encoding, rfc2616

If no charset parameter is specified in the Content-Type header, [RFC2616 section 3.7.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html) seems to imply ISO8859-1 should be assumed for media types of subtype "text":

> When no explicit charset parameter is
> provided by the sender, media subtypes
> of the "text" type are defined to have
> a default charset value of
> "ISO-8859-1" when received via HTTP.
>
> Data in character sets other than
> "ISO-8859-1" or its subsets MUST be
> labeled with an appropriate charset
> value.

However, I routinely see applications that serve up Javascript files with Content-Type values like "application/x-javascript" (i.e. no charset param), even when these scripts contain non-ASCII UTF-8 characters, which would be corrupt if interpreted as ISO8859-1.

This does not seem to pose problems to clients. How do clients know to interpret the bytes as UTF-8? Is there a rule for other character-data subtypes that implies UTF-8 should be the default? Where is this documented?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All major browsers I've checked (IE, FF and Opera) completely **ignore the RFC specification** in this part.

If you are interested in the algorithm to auto-detect charset by data, look at [Mozilla Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/intl/UniversalCharsetDetection.html) link.

Just a small note about content types: **Only text has character sets**. It's reasonable to assume that browsers handle application/x-javascript the same as they handle text/javascript ( except IE6, but that's another subject ).

**Internet Explorer** will use the default charset (probably stored at registry), as noted:

> By default, Internet Explorer uses the
>   character set specified in the HTTP
>   content type returned by the server to
>   determine this translation. If this
>   parameter is not given, Internet
>   Explorer uses the character set
>   specified by the meta  element in the
>   document. **It uses the user's
>   preferences** if no meta element is
>   specified.

*Source*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537500%28VS.85%29.aspx

**Mozilla Firefox** attempts to auto-detect the charset, as pointed here:

> This paper presents three types of auto-detection methods to determine encodings of documents **without explicit charset declaration**.

*Source*: http://www.mozilla.org/projects/intl/UniversalCharsetDetection.html

**Opera** uses auto-detection too, as documented:

> If the transport protocol provides an encoding name, that is used. If not, Opera will look at the page for a charset declaration. **If this is missing, Opera will attempt to auto-detect the encoding**, using the domain name to see if the script is a CJK script, and if so which one. Opera can also auto-detect UTF-8.

*Source*: http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/opera9/

Answer (score 2):

As described in [RFC 4329](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329), also `application/javascript` can have a `charset` parameter. The other question is the handling of browser implementations. Sorry, but not tested.

Answer (score 2):

In the absense of the `charset` parameter, the character encoding can be specified in the **content**. Here are some approaches taken by several content types:

**HTML** - Via the [meta tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#Specifying_the_document.27s_character_encoding):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

**HTML5** variant:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

**XML** (XHTML, KML) - Via the [XML declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml#Key_terminology):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

**Text** - Via the [Byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). For example, for **UTF-8** the first three bytes of a file in hexadecimal:

```
EF BB BF
```

As distinct from the character set associated with the document, note also that non-ASCII characters can be encoded via ASCII character sequences using various approaches:

**HTML** - Via [character references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#HTML_character_references):

```
&#nnnn;
&#xhhhh;
```

**XML** - Via [character references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_characters_references#XML_character_references):

```
&amp;
&defined-entity;
```

**JSON** - Via the [escaping mechanism](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

```
\u005C
\uD834\uDD1E
```

Now, with respect to the the HTTP 1.1 protocol, [RFC 2616 says this about charset](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.7.1):

> The "charset" parameter is used with some media types to define the
> character set (section 3.4) of the data. When no explicit charset
> parameter is provided by the sender, media subtypes of the "text" type
> are defined to have a default charset value of "ISO-8859-1" when
> received via HTTP. Data in character sets other than "ISO-8859-1" or
> its subsets MUST be labeled with an appropriate charset value. See
> section 3.4.1 for compatibility problems.

So, my interpretation of the above is that one *cannot* assume a default character set *except* for media subtypes of the type "text." Of course, we live in the real world and implementers do not always follow the rules. As described in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2349239/1497596), the various web browser vendors have implemented their own strategies for determining the document character set when it is not explicitly specified. One can assume that vendors of other clients (e.g., Google Earth) also implement their own strategies.

Comment: Character references or escapes have nothing to do at all with the character encoding of the enclosing document...

Comment: @Julian - Agreed. I restructured my answer accordingly. (I do feel that including mention of character references and escaping is worthwhile.)

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 4329](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt) defines the "application/javascript" media type as a replacement for "text/javascript", "application/x-javascript", and other similar types.  Section 4.2 establishes the default character encoding to be UTF-8 when no explicit "charset" parameter is available and no Unicode BOM is present at the front of the data.

Comment: My interpretation of **section 4.2** is *not* to assume that UTF-8 is the default character encoding. In addition, the intro to **section 4** states: "How implementations determine the character encoding scheme can be subject to processing rules that are out of the scope of this document."

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit special for XMLHttpRequest and is described here: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/

Answer (score 0):

Pointing out the obvious: "application/x-javascript" is not a subtype of "text".

Also, the text in RFC 2616 is outdated. The next revision of HTTP/1.1 will not define a default. See RFC 6657 for further information.

Comment: Agree - so the question is: Is there a rule for character-data subtypes other than "text"? If so, where is this documented?

Comment: There is no general rule, as the media type might not be character based in the first place...

Comment: The question is specifically about those media types that suggest character data. If there is no general rule, are there specific rules for different media types? Where are they documented?

There must be at least *some* rules, given that clients have to make a decision on how to interpret the bytes.

Comment: Specific rules should be in the document the media type registration points to, such as http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3023#section-3.2 for application/xml.