# text/plain vs text/javascript

Tags: php, http-headers, mime-types, content-type

I noticed that there's a whole bunch of different content types, some of them seem redundant.

Wouldn't a js file that's served as `text/plain` work just as well as if it was served with `text/javasctipt`?

I plan on making a page that's serve-able as a `ajax`/`json`/`jsonp` file (with or without a callback) or as a plain page that users on a dumb phone or with no `js` can view as a text file.

Is there any disadvantage as always displaying a page as `text/plain` ? Will it ever be a problem if I'm getting it as a script? What about the inverse?

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101394/javascript-mime-type , theres detailed explanation about javascript mime type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Wouldn't a js file that's served as text/plain work just as well as if it was served with text/javasctipt?

Only if it would be executed as JavaScript regardless. If `text/plain` meant something to the client distinct from `text/javascript` then the effects would (could) be different. Fortunately it usually doesn't when the browser loads it due to a `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

An advantage of using text/javascript is that it will allow you to include non '.js' postfixed files and they will be rendered as javascript.

For instance, I usually have a global.config file - which is a javascript written configuration object.  I can use the postfix '.config' which is very helpful visually - but still use have it render as javascript.

Comment: What do you mean "rendered as javascript" ?

Comment: I think **interpreted** is a better word.

Comment: @Blender: won't the js still run tho?

Comment: If it's included in a `<script>` tag, sure.

Answer (score 0):

When a Javascript is inserted dynamically, the navigator will give you correct events and states of reception (readyState with Intrenet Explorer, onload with FireFox) if the content is type "text/javascript". It can make wrong or lazy response if it's "text/plain".