# Set my JS MIME type to "text/javascript"

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, mime-types

According to this: [Javascript MIME Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101394/javascript-mime-type), it seems that I should be serving my JS as "text/javascript". When I inspect the network communication between my browser and localhost (or my server), the MIME type of the JS that are hosted on my web server is application/x-javascript. The JS from Google CDN (e.g. jQuery) is text/javascript.

I want to make my JS become text/javascript. In my .htaccess, I tried adding this: `AddType text/javascript .js`, but  it  didn't change my MIME type.

Suggestions?

Comment: It should be `application/javascript`. No browser cares if it is `application/x-javascript` though. The best way to fix that would be to upgrade the underlying system, which has an out of date mime.types file.

Comment: "No browser" or "no CURRENT browser?" Seems from the link that IE might have an issue. And though it seems the `application/javascript` is the "proper" MIME type, I'm trying to do as Google and use `text/javascript`.

Comment: `application/x-javascript` appears on both my WAMP and LAMP system. I'm thinking that somehow my code, .htaccess, etc. is the culprit.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you'd need or want to change this, do you have to support ancient browsers?

Answer (score 12):

The `AddType` directive should be sufficient enough unless there's something that's forcing the type, but you can also try:

```
<Files "*.js">
    ForceType text/javascript
</Files>
```

A better solution may be to look through your vhost/server config and all of the apache config files (that may be included by default in your config) for instances of `application/x-javascript` to see how that's being set. It may be better to just change it there instead of htaccess file, which may not have the neccessary override options (mod_mime's `AddType` and `ForceType`, for example, require the **FileInfo** `AllowOverride` option).

Answer (score 3):

you need to change your settings in mimes.types file found in your apache conf folder. Change

```
application/javascript          js
```

to

```
text/javascript                 js
```

and restart apache, you should see the change