# MIME type in Chrome error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mime-types

When I load my web application in Chrome it shows the folliwing in the console log:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain:

I think this is the cause of the problems I've been having (perfectly valid functions that work in the console, but not in the .js script files).

I've read that the solution is to put your `<script type=`s to `"application/javascript"`. I have tried this, but it failed. Is there another solution?

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101394/javascript-mime-type

Comment: OK, @Cube32, I've read that and it says that I don't need a type, so does that mean it can't be the cause of my problems?

Comment: You didn't actually specify what the root problem was, so there's no way of knowing if it's related - edit your question and add the underlying problem in.

Comment: @Cube32 alright thanks anyway, if you submit your earlier comment as an answer i'll accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

theres an error with your server-sided code, the server sends "text/plain" when the browser expects "text/javascript"

.. how to fix this depends on what server you use (lighthttpd / apache / nginx / etc) , but.. if you have some scripting language like PHP (which nearly all webservers has these days) , you can use that to customize the MIME.. like

jsstuff.js.php

```
<?php header("content-type: text/javascript");?>
//javascript goes here!
```