# Tumblr js output MIME type error

Tags: javascript, tumblr, mime, htmltext

I have been reading up on all the posts I could find about this particular problem, but nothing has explicitly solved my problem. So, I thought I would post about my specific issue.

I have been running a tumblr.com/js feed into my website for the past few months and now it has suddenly broken.

I am getting the (seemingly common) error in Chrome:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://peerlesstree.tumblr.com/js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Just a few months ago it was successfully importing tumblr content into an div with the simple html tag:

```
<div class="tumblrposts">

     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://peerlesstree.tumblr.com/js"></script>

</div>
```

I have no idea why this has suddenly stopped working and can't seem to find the specific fix for this issue. I have seen posts referring people to mime-type settings but I have not yet been able to implement one to make this work.

I am not trying to duplicate these other chrome mime type error questions, I just can't make the connection between my specific tumblr/js problem and the other post answers I have read.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is Tumblr is not serving the script with the correct mime type (e.g. `text/javascript`), though they probably did in the past (it worked for you at one point). The other posts offer solutions, assuming you control the server, which you don't. You should contact Tumblr support.

Comment: How do you know about the `/js` link? I've never seen it before.

Comment: Who hosts your website? Do you have access to a control panel to edit mime types? Depending on the server you may have an .htaccess file, httpd.conf, or another type of config file in your root where you can edit the mime types if you have permissions.

Comment: @approxiblue I forget exactly how I found this method. It was a result of a long coffee fueled journey into night...

Comment: @lharby I do have access to the hosting, and have found the custom mime type entry page, BUT I am not sure what entry to add to make it work again...

Comment: Maybe show us a screen shot. what type of config is it? .htaccess file.

Comment: Or it's a control panel? It should be entered like this: text/javascript   .js

Comment: It's pretty odd though, as I would have thought most hosts would have this enabled by default.

Comment: yes that mime type is already in the default list. i think the problem is related to the incoming file being labeled as type = text/html. The script is still running properly in my old version of firefox FF48.0.2. It is odd that I haven't updated chrome and that it was working previously.

Comment: I am using cPanel through godaddy. my .htacess is blank still untouched. the response header says "Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8" even though it is clearly js. I have contacted tumblr support about this and hopefully they will be getting back to me with an answer!

Comment: I am trying to load the /js into a .php to overwrtie the content-type and then trigger it from my html with. `<?php 
header("Content-type: text/javascript");

$yolo = "
<script src=\"http://peerlesstree.tumblr.com/js\"></script> 
";

echo $yolo;

?>` then calling it with `<script type="text/javascript" src="js.php"></script>` but i have not yet gotten it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expands on the basic answer I found here : [mime-type-in-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833430/mime-type-in-chrome-error?rq=1)

the php file controls the Content-type and then uses readfile() to access the js content.

php:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/javascript"); readfile("http://peerlesstree.tumblr.com/js");?>
```

then the html calls the php file as if it were js.

html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.php"></script>
```