# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/x-javascript

Tags: php, html

I have a simple php file having only:

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("content-type:application/javascript");
echo "var md = 0 ";
```

In my html file I am calling the php file in `iframe`:

```
<iframe src="../API/index.php?i=MTQ4MDkyMDY1Mg==&d" width="100" height="100"></iframe>
```

While using the link in script tag its working but when I try to use it in `iframe` I'm getting the mime application/javascript error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MIME type in Chrome error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833430/mime-type-in-chrome-error)

Comment: @WaqasBukhary can u elaborate please

Comment: I mean did you try header("content-type: text/javascript"); instead of header("content-type:application/javascript");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101394/javascript-mime-type

Comment: @WaqasBukhary yes i did tried that too

Comment: Can you also share your Iframe code too. I think JS is not allowed in iframe only html is allowed.

Comment: @WaqasBukhary here it is <iframe src="../API/index.php?i=MTQ4MDkyMDY1Mg==&d" width="100" height="100" type="application/javascript"></iframe>

Comment: we don't use a type attribute in iframe, because only html is allowed.

Comment: i had tried without type too still no effect

Answer (score 2):

An Iframe can only accept html document.

You can do the js inside your html.

```
<iframe src="../API/index.php?i=MTQ4MDkyMDY1Mg==&d"></iframe>
```

and inside the php, remove all headers and do...

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>var md = 0; </script>";
```

Comment: thanks for the comment  but still the error is there m working on the same error the whole day

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this error i.e  the output is Javascript. What I need to do is create another file with  and then use this file in the iframe. Just posted this answer if anyone else got the same error.