# The jquery plugin I am trying to make work on my Windows 7 Internet Explorer IE7 browser here is http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have some odd experience with my Windows 7 Internet Explorer IE7 browser here. The jquery plugin
I am trying to make work on my Windows 7 Internet Explorer IE7 browser here is http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/. This jquery plugin is not working on Windows 7 Internet Explorer IE7 browser but is running properly on Red Hat Linux LAMP server with Internet Explorer 7. I am running Wampserver2.4-x86 on Dell Inspiron.

Here is my index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>jVectorMap demo</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-jvectormap-us-aea-en.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="USA-map" style="width: 1200px; height: 800px"></div>
  <script language="javascript">
    function processOrder() {
   var pluginContainer = $("#USA-map");
       pluginContainer.vectorMap({map: 'jquery-jvectormap-us-aea-en'});
    }
  </script>
</body>
<body>
<Script Language="JavaScript">
  processOrder();
</Script>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I the only one who have this experience? or do we have some extra code to make it works for Wampserver2.4-x86? thanks before.

Comment: You need to give us sow more info. What is the expected result of the script, and in what way does it currently fail?

Comment: @michaelward82, THe expected result of the script is a clickable image map of the USA,Please see http:/www.stackoverflow.com/questions/2820303/quickest-way-to-make-clickable-imagemap-of-the-us.It currently fails on Wampserver2.4-x86 by showing a blank view. Thanks, Frank

Comment: ever tried it with a browser that has a developer console (like chrome), whats telling you the log? could there be a problem with permissions, file rights,...?

Comment: @bbuecherl, Thank you for your developer console suggestion. It was not a problem with permissions or file rights. The developer console helped me find my HTML syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

The server appears to return the content mime type of "application/x-javascript".

Officially, the server should return "application/javascript" see question [Javascript MIME Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101394/javascript-mime-type)

However, for compatibility purposes, mainly with IE, it is currently preferable to return the content mime-type of "text/javascript".

Change instances of "application/x-javascript" in your apache config file to "text/javascript" and restart your apache server.

Comment: I tested your fix. Also, I fixed my original index.html to remove extra HTML body  statements.

Answer (score 0):

The USA image vectormap plug in is now working on Windows 7 Wampserver2.4-x86. Thank you.

### index.html

jVectorMap demo 
  
 
 
 


  
  
    function processOrder() {
     var pluginContainer = $("#USA-map");
         pluginContainer.vectorMap({map: 'us_aea_en'});
    }

foo.js contains one line: processOrder();