# Why has the request Accept: */* when the browser is asking for a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, http

The html source is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

However debugging the http request (with Fiddler) it clearly seems that browser (Chrome) issues the `GET` request for myscript.js with `Accept */*`.

Is this normal?

Interestingly this issue is not true for CSS files. The browser is correctly asking them `Accept: text/css,*/*`

(In a programmed proxy server) I would like to detect which requests are for javascript files. I thought I can rely on Accept in request header...

Comment: The MIME type of Javascript files is [somewhat wishy washy.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101394/javascript-mime-type) No real reason for the browser to care about it too much in the request.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this normal?

Yes

> (In a programmed proxy server) I would like to detect which requests are for javascript files. I thought I can rely on Accept in request header...

You can't. Look at the content-type in the response header instead.

Comment: But why.... :-). Unfortunately I have to decide what to do with the request _before_ I am forwarding it, so I have no response in that time

Comment: Because browsers never felt the need to handle the possibility that someone might do content type negotiation for a JavaScript resource.

Comment: What is the difference of css and js? (this point of view).  This is a poetic question no answers need...