# Why isn't Leverage browser caching not working for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, caching, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

When running my site through the Google page speed test it says I need "Leverage browser caching
Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network."

It then lists my internal Javascript files, why does the below not work and fix this?

This is how much htaccess file looks:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

<FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl|jpg|png|gif)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The official mime-type for Javascript is `application/javascript`, try this instead.

Source http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt

The `x-` stands for "experimental" and is not used with Javascripts anymore.

All of those combinations are either deprecated, obsolete or outdated:

```
text/x-javascript
text/javascript
application/x-javascript
application/ecmascript
```

**There are more wrong mime-types in your config:**

Wrong: `image/x-icon`
Right: `image/vnd.microsoft.icon`

Source: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/image/vnd.microsoft.icon

Wrong: `application/x-pdf`
Right: `application/pdf`

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3778

Comment: I have tried this but still no luck, I am on 1and1 and it looks like it uses application/x-javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified that files of type text/x-javascript should be cacheable, but have you told the webserver how to recognise such files? As DanFromGermany says, the mimetype really should be [application/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101394/javascript-mime-type) however within your webserver this is just an arbitrary label. Your webserver *may* already be configured to recognise files ending in `.js` as javascript, in which case its simply a matter of changing the corresponding line in the mod_expires block. You can see the mimetype being returned by webserver in firebug, iehttpheaders, using wireshark to monitor a connection or with wget / curl from the command line.

If your webserver is returning something other than `application/javascript` or `text/x-javascript` then check for an entry in the `mime.types` file in the directory containing your apache config.

Comment: I have tried this but still no luck, I am on 1and1 and it looks like it uses application/x-javascript.

Comment: 1and1 hosting is appallingly bad, however the issue is not insurmountable if you can apply changes via htaccess. Just change the line in the mod_expires to match the mimetype the webserver is using.

Comment: It uses application/x-javascript which was already there, so it still isn't working for some reason.

Comment: Erm actually we talked about text/x-javascript, application/javascript but not application/x-javascript

Comment: There's no obvious reason why your config would work for other filetypes but not for javascript: you could try changing the values to confirm whether the htaccess file is having any impact at all, but then would reverse engineering the problems with 1and1's hosting help to fix the problem? Similarly there are other ways to make the content cacheable, but you are paying 1and1 for support - get them to advise.

Answer (score 0):

Check your hosting configuration.
I was using Cpanel's "SuperCacher services": 
static cache
Dynamic cache
Memcache

they were overriding my .htaccess settings and caused this issue.
once i disabled them the issue went away.